# Using button rather than a link for single page web app

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-markup

I'm creating a web app that has a list of commands that change elements on a single page. The page is 100% dependant on JavaScript. I therefore coded these links as:

```
<a href="#">Command #1</a>
```

Doubting that this is semantically correct, I found numerous places stating that I should use a `button` instead.

This makes sense, but means I have to alter the style of a button to look like a link, which feels hacky. Is this the correct method?

Comment: Something being "semantically correct" is not a vague concept. Also, the answer I selected is clearly a "solid answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 spec is pretty clear in that you shouldn't use [`a`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-a-element.html#the-a-element):

> If the `a` element has an `href` attribute, then it represents a hyperlink (a hypertext anchor).

The [definition of "hyperlink"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#hyperlink) is:

> These are links to other resources […]

So don't use `a` for "actions" on your single page web app.

You should go with [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)  or resp. [`input`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html#the-input-element) (I'd say both with `type` value of `button`).

If you like to dive into newer HTML5 stuff, take a look at [`menu`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-menu-element.html#the-menu-element) and [`command`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-command-element.html#the-command-element).

---

Just to be sure: you shouldn't "enhance" other elements (like `span` or `div`) with JS to act like links/buttons. This wouldn't be accessible without further work, if at all.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. The added benefit of the button is that it gives me the ability to disable them. Never knew about command, that looks perfect. Thanks!

Comment: A “link to other resources” may well refer to a different state of the current page. Thus, the wording of the HTML5 draft does not give any solid answer to the question. The `menu` and `command` element hardly have browser support worth mentioning. There is no solid reason why `span` or `div` or other elements could not be used as JavaScript-driven controls in a context where JavaScript support is required anyway. Buttons are a natural way, but not the only one.

Comment: @Jukka: "a different state of the current page" → do you mean referring to a `id`/`name` in the URL fragment? Or something else?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela A different state of the page is not a resource. The spec therefore gives a solid answer.

Answer (score 2):

The style you give to the element is irrelevant to whether or not it's semantically correct code, so I wouldn't worry too much about that.

`Links` are meant to, well, link the user between pages on the web.

HTML `Input` elements are meant to take user input and do things with them.

Based on this simple heuristic, I'd say go with a button!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using links is semantically incorrect. If it makes you feel better, you can style your links as buttons.

Otherwise, if that still rubs you the wrong way, there's nothing wrong with styling a button to look like a link. The functionality of your app should have little to do with how you present your buttons, as long as they do the same thing and fit within your expectations.

As mentioned in the comments, if you wish to use buttons, bear in mind that they style as form elements and can be more difficult that working with an anchor tag.

Comment: Or styling a `<span>` to look like a link.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `button` elements style like form controls when it comes to sizing. sometimes it can be more work to get a `button` or `input` of `submit/reset` to align with other elements if you originally used a non-form element such as an `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Both are technically fine to use. For me, if it is a text link, then I'd use the `<a>` tag and if it is a form button or image, use `<button>`. That way you are consistent with what the elements intended uses are.

Answer (score 0):

Generally i prefer using div's for these things. Links come with a lot of inherent browser styling, even more so for buttons. Div's only rule is display:block. So it's saves me some reset css lines. Also it saves me some js code to prevent default behaviour. Add that to the fact that there is no correct semantic choice, then using div's makes a lot of sense.

Comment: How do keyboard users activate your "`div` button"?

Comment: That's a bad practice for accessibility. If your reasoning is default styling, try using a css reset.